# Undefined variable in IF statement (but seems correctly declared)

Tags: php, html, nginx, undefined

Something makes me crazy, I get an Undefined variable if I declare a variable in an IF statement. If I declare this variable above the IF statement, the PHP Notice disapear.

My code :

```
if($tab_sel==FILENAME_DEFAULT){ // FILENAME_DEFAULT = index.php
  if(...){
       some functions
  }
  $nb_pages=ceil($count/$limit) : 0;
}
echo $nb_pages; //4000 is displayed on the page (OK),
```

but in the Nginx log, I get :

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice : Undefined variable nb_pages in /.../index.php
```

but when I load the page, I can see that nb_page is displayed correctly (example: value is 4000), but in the log, undefined variable..

In my example, if I declare nb_pages above "if($tab_sel==FILENAME_DEFAULT){", the undefined disapear.

Any idea?

Comment: if `$tab_sel != 'index.php'` then `$nb_pages` would not be defined.

Comment: if only $tab_sel==FILENAME_DEFAULT, the $nb_pages is defined.

Comment: thanks but FILENAME_DEFAULT=index.php, otherwise I would not see nb_pages=4000 on the page

Comment: You're confused on Variable scope.  I'm willing to bet the error is actually being thrown at the echo nb_page line.  If you define the nb_page inside the if block, it will only be available for the life of the if block. -- unless there's documentation that states otherwise.

Comment: you are sure of that Dan? I think we can declare a variable inside a if block and use it outside, no?

Comment: Yes @Julian, I'm sorry - you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found why it didn't work :

```
in case of a 404 error page (called FILENAME_404)
```

I also use the index.php file in which I call the variables undeclared.

that's why the Nginx error said about **index.php**, not because it doesn't go into `if($tab_sel==FILENAME_DEFAULT){` but because in some other cases I use also **index.php** with `tab_sel=FILENAME_404`

thank you everyone!

Comment: That's exactly what I said. In those cases, the condition won't match. That's what's causing the warning, because of those cases.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're creating the variable inside a if that can fail to pass. In this case, the variable would be undefined and PHP will throw an error since it couldn't find the variable that you are asking for afterwards.

Declare it before the if and you will be just fine.

```
$nb_pages;
if($tab_sel==FILENAME_DEFAULT){ 
  if(...){
```

Comment: yes but why it should be declared outside the IF, IF statements are not a php scope, right ? only functions are php scope, no?

Comment: @Julien No. If the outer if-statement returns false, the variable is never created, thus it can throw an undefined variable error.

Comment: You're declaring the variable only inside the if, of course you can use it if the if works, but if the condition fails, the variable will never be declared.

Comment: yes but indeed it goes in the if, otherwise I would not see nb_pages=4000 on the site, no? and even in the dev server (I use easyphp), there is no error, and it shows well 4000, but on nginx log, I get this warning, I don't understand..

Comment: Well, it will work if the condition matches. The warning in the log is saying that it could throw an error in case of non-matching condition, that's why it's a warning.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might me an environment issue. Try to put both `FILENAME_DEFAULT` and `$nb_pages` into a log file:

```
file_put_contents(
    'test.log',
    date('[Y-m-d H:i:s] ') 
    . FILENAME_DEFAULT . "\t" . @$nb_pages . PHP_EOL,
    FILE_APPEND
);
```

The `@` will prevent the warning message.